# How to put selected on one particular option inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I am trying to echo out "selected" on a value inside my array, within a foreach. If the form is false and my customer has already entered a particular value in my select, return it so he doesn't fill it again! That's what I am trying to do...

```
<?php
 $marques = array('Word','Word1','Word20','Word46','Word9797');
        foreach ($marques as $marque => $value) 
        {
        if (isset($_POST['marque']) && $_POST['marque'] == $value[$_POST['marque']]) {
            echo '<option value="'.$_POST["marque"].'">'.$value[$_POST["marque"]].'</option>';
        }
            echo '<option value="'.$marque.'">'.$value.'</option>'; 
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$marques = array('Word', 'Word1', 'Word20', 'Word46', 'Word9797');

foreach ($marques as $marque) 
   echo '<option value="'.$marque.'" '.(($marque == $_POST['marque']) ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$marque.'</option>';
?>
```

Comment: There are some errors with the '' and "" but thanks! This is working well :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
<?php
    $marques = array('Word','Word1','Word20','Word46','Word9797');

    foreach ($marques as $marque => $value) {
        $setItSelected = '';
        if (isset($_POST['marque']) && $_POST['marque'] == $marque) {
            $setItSelected = 'selected';
        }

        echo '<option value="'.$marque.'" '.$setItSelected.'>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Great job! That was exactly what I was looking for. Quite simple, clean, boum. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, there is an error. If you press on Submit button when this select is empty, it will put the first one instead of a empty option.

Comment: It is not error. I just changed your code to able the select option change to selected state when recieved by POST parameter is in array.

Answer (score 0):

Changing what's inside the value attribute doesn't make the item more or less selected. You need to add the selected attribute, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

The output:ed html should look something like:

```
<option value="id" selected>some text</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $marques = array('Word','Word1','Word20','Word46','Word9797');
        foreach ($marques as $marque) 
        {
        if (isset($_POST['marque']) && $_POST['marque'] == $marque') 
            echo '<option value="'.$marque.'" selected>'.$marque.'</option>';

        else
             echo '<option value="'.$marque.'">'.$marque.'</option>'; 
        }
    ?>
```

Your Array is one dimension, you can't use "=>" 
For select option you must add the "selected" attribute too at your option tag